# NetSuite "INVALID_LOGIN Error" when sending GET request to RESTlet in PHP

Tags: php, curl, netsuite

A few months ago I implemented a RESTlet solution that receives a POST request from a PHP script. I am now extending the solution to send a GET request to a RESTlet with a different ID. The issue is that the authentication is only successful when the request is sent to a URL without the query string. We need to pass the query string to the RESTlet in order for it to execute.

Appending the query string to the URL throws a 403 INVALID_LOGIN error, and calling the RESTlet without it throws an exception for a missing paramter (as expected).

```
private function setAuthentication() {
      $oauthNonce = md5(mt_rand());
      $oauthTimestamp = time();
      $baseString = $this->requestType."&".urlencode($this->url)."&".urlencode(
          "deploy=".$this->deployID
          ."&oauth_consumer_key=".$this->consumerKey
          ."&oauth_nonce=".$oauthNonce
          ."&oauth_signature_method=".$this->oauthSigMethod
          ."&oauth_timestamp=".$oauthTimestamp
          ."&oauth_token=".$this->tokenID
          ."&oauth_version=".$this->oauthVersion
          ."&realm=".$this->account
          ."&script=".$this->scriptID
        );
      $sigString = urlencode($this->consumerSecret).'&'.urlencode($this->tokenSecret);
      $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $baseString, $sigString, true));
      $authHeader = "OAuth "
        . 'oauth_signature="' . rawurlencode($signature) . '", '
        . 'oauth_version="' . rawurlencode($this->oauthVersion) . '", '
        . 'oauth_nonce="' . rawurlencode($oauthNonce) . '", '
        . 'oauth_signature_method="' . rawurlencode($this->oauthSigMethod) . '", '
        . 'oauth_consumer_key="' . rawurlencode($this->consumerKey) . '", '
        . 'oauth_token="' . rawurlencode($this->tokenID) . '", '  
        . 'oauth_timestamp="' . rawurlencode($oauthTimestamp) . '", '
        . 'realm="' . rawurlencode($this->account) .'"';
        return $authHeader;
    }

public function callGetRestlet() {
      $this->requestType = 'GET';
        $authorizationHeader = $this->setAuthentication();
        $urlQueryAppend = http_build_query(array('id' => $this->queryString));
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $this->requestType);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url. '?&script='. $this->scriptID. '&deploy='. $this->deployID.'&realm=' . $this->account);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            'Authorization: '.$authorizationHeader,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
      ]);
      $response = array();
      $response['request'] = json_decode($this->queryString);
      $response['response']['body'] = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
      $response['response']['code']  = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $response;
    }
```

I know the credentials are okay as the RESTlet's event log shows the exception when the parameter isn't provided. The above throws the exception.

When the CURLOPT_URL is modified to include the querystring it throws the 403:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url. '?&script='. $this->scriptID. '&deploy='. $this->deployID.'&realm=' . $this->account.'&'.$urlQueryAppend);
```

This code was slightly modified from an answer to a different question that asked about a POST request.

Is the error being thrown as a result of setting the request headers?

Comment: `?&script=` doesn't look right. You should be building out query strings with [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Comment: I know it looks a bit strange. That URL structure successfully authenticates and executes the script on a POST request. When the code is used for a GET request it rejects the authentication when the id querystring parameter is provided. I have also used CURLOPT_POSTFILEDS to provide the parameters with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the id parameter to the base string after the deploy ID resolved the issue. I was adding it to the end, but in this case it looks like the order of the parameters matters.

```
private function setAuthentication() {
   $oauthNonce = md5(mt_rand());
   $oauthTimestamp = time();
   $baseString = $this->requestType."&".urlencode($this->url)."&".urlencode(
        "deploy=".$this->deployID
        ."&id=".$this->queryString
        ."&oauth_consumer_key=".$this->consumerKey
        ."&oauth_nonce=".$oauthNonce
        ."&oauth_signature_method=".$this->oauthSigMethod
        ."&oauth_timestamp=".$oauthTimestamp
        ."&oauth_token=".$this->tokenID
        ."&oauth_version=".$this->oauthVersion
        ."&script=".$this->scriptID
      );
   $sigString = urlencode($this->consumerSecret).'&'.urlencode($this->tokenSecret);
   $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $baseString, $sigString, true));
   $authHeader = "OAuth "
      . 'oauth_signature="' . rawurlencode($signature) . '", '
      . 'oauth_version="' . rawurlencode($this->oauthVersion) . '", '
      . 'oauth_nonce="' . rawurlencode($oauthNonce) . '", '
      . 'oauth_signature_method="' . rawurlencode($this->oauthSigMethod) . '", ' /** must be HMAC-SHA256 as SHA1 is deprecated **/
      . 'oauth_consumer_key="' . rawurlencode($this->consumerKey) . '", '
      . 'oauth_token="' . rawurlencode($this->tokenID) . '", '  
      . 'oauth_timestamp="' . rawurlencode($oauthTimestamp) . '", '
      . 'realm="' . rawurlencode($this->account) .'"';
     return $authHeader;
}

public function callGetRestlet() {
      $this->requestType = 'GET';
      $parameters = http_build_query(
        array(
          'script' => $this->scriptID,
          'deploy' => $this->deployID,
          'id' => $this->queryString,
        )
      );
      $authorizationHeader = $this->setAuthentication();
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $this->requestType);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url. '?'.$parameters);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            'Authorization: '.$authorizationHeader,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
      ]);
      $response = array();
      $response['request'] = $this->url. '?'.$parameters;
      $response['response']['body'] = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
      $response['response']['code']  = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $response;
    }
```

Comment: For anyone finding this in 2021.. need to use $oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA256'; and hash_hmac("sha256"